# c++ convert domain name to IP address with getaddrinfo

Tags: c++, ip, domain-name, getaddrinfo

Hello i created a function using the depreciated gethostbyname to convert a domain name to an IP address and it works great, however this causes lots of warnings and my work wants me to use the newer getaddrinfo.

While i am able to get getaddrinfo working and it prints out the IP address it also prints out the gateway information and more but all i want is the IP address of the domain name. From placing break points in the function i can see it is the 5th variable in the structure though again my work does not want me to just loop through 5 times as this could change in the future "I doubt that but still.."

So i ask is there a way i can access the structure or set - read a flag to get just the IP address of the host name?

Here is my code new both the old and new function

```
// OLD FUNCTION
std::string getHostNameIpAddress(const std::string& a_domainName)
{
  struct in_addr addr;
  std::string ipAddress;
  WSADATA wsaData;

  int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

  if (iResult != 0)
  {
     ErrorMessage("WSAStartup failed: " << iResult);
  }
  else
  {
     struct hostent* remoteHost = gethostbyname(a_domainName.c_str());

     if (remoteHost == NULL)
     {
        DWORD dwError = WSAGetLastError();
        if (dwError != 0) {
           if (dwError == WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND)
           {
              ErrorMessage("Host not found.");
           }
           else if (dwError == WSANO_DATA)
           {
              ErrorMessage("No domain name record found.");
           }
           else
           {
              ErrorMessage("Domain name lookup failed with error: " << dwError);
           }
        }
     }
     else
     {
        addr.s_addr = *(u_long*)remoteHost->h_addr_list[0];
        TechSupportTraceA("IP Address: " << inet_ntoa(addr));
        ipAddress = inet_ntoa(addr);
     }
  }
  return ipAddress;
}
```

And the new function using getaddrinfo which i copied from a tutorial with minor adjustments.

```
std::string getHostNameIpAddress(const char* a_domainName)
{
  struct addrinfo hints, * res;
  int errcode;
  char addrstr[100];
  void* ptr;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags |= AI_CANONNAME;

  errcode = getaddrinfo(a_domainName, NULL, &hints, &res);
  if (errcode != 0)
  {
     cout("getaddrinfo failed with error: " << errcode);
     WSACleanup();
     return "";
  }

  cout("Host: " << a_domainName);

  while (res)
  {
     switch (res->ai_family)
     {
     case AF_INET:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in*) res->ai_addr)->sin_addr;
        inet_ntop(res->ai_family, ptr, addrstr, 100);
        break;
     case AF_INET6:
        ptr = &((struct sockaddr_in6*) res->ai_addr)->sin6_addr;
        inet_ntop(res->ai_family, ptr, addrstr, 100);
        break;          
     }

     // domain name IP is the 5th 
     cout("IPv" << (res->ai_family == PF_INET6 ? "6" : "4") << " address = " << addrstr)    

     res = res->ai_next;
  }

  return addrstr; / / retuns wrong address as it interates past the domain name to the gateway ip
```

}

Comment: Off topic but... the memory allocated by `getaddrinfo` should be freed by a subsequent call to `freeaddrinfo`.  As it stands you have a memory leak.